Problems in classroom.yml file where no marks displayed at github classroom after running github action for autograding Python tests
my classroom.yml file got problems where no marks displayed at github classroom after running github action for Python tests. would like to ask for help on how to show marks based on the number of Python tests scored by students. So, how to solve this problem by correcting classroom.yml file.
Below are my print-screen images taken after assignment submission by student.


This is the classroom.yml content:
name: GitHub Classroom Workflow

on: push
    
jobs:
  build:
    name: Autograding
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: education/autograding@v1

This is the autograding.json for autograding the students' Python assignment.
{
    "tests": [
      {
        "name": "parte1",
        "setup": "sudo -H pip3 install -r requirements.txt",
        "run": "pytest test_assignment.py::test_hello",
        "input": "",
        "output": "",
        "comparison": "included",
        "timeout": 5,
        "points": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "parte2",
        "setup": "sudo -H pip3 install -r requirements.txt",
        "run": "pytest test_assignment.py::test_add_two",
        "input": "",
        "output": "",
        "comparison": "included",
        "timeout": 5,
        "points": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "parte3",
        "setup": "sudo -H pip3 install -r requirements.txt",
        "run": "pytest test_assignment.py::test_zero_array",
        "input": "",
        "output": "",
        "comparison": "included",
        "timeout": 5,
        "points": 1
      }
    ]
  }


Please copy your code instead of sending screenshots of it, for more info look at How do I ask a good question?
